# solving the derivative of a function with cos

Tags: calculus, derivatives

my question is 
`y=cos^4(2x^2-1)`

here is my work

`Dy/dx=4cos^3(2x^2-1) d/dx cos(2x^2-1)
Dy/dx=4cos^3(2x^2-1) (-d/dx(2x^2-1)sin(2x^2-1))
Dy/dx=-4cos^3(2x^2-1)sin(2x^2-1)(4x)
$$dy/dx=-16x\cos^3(2x^2-1)\sin(2x^2-1)$$

any idea on where i went wrong

Comment: you are right, nice answer

Comment: Why do you believe your answer is wrong?  (Take care that given answers, such as the one WolframAlpha produces, differ only by the application of trig relations.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule),

$$\frac{d\{\cos^4(2x^2-1)\}}{dx}$$

$$=\frac{d\{\cos^4(2x^2-1)\}}{d\{\cos(2x^2-1)\}}\cdot\frac{d\{\cos(2x^2-1)\}}{dx}$$

$$=4\cos^3(2x^2-1)\cdot\frac{d\{\cos(2x^2-1)\}}{d(2x^2-1)}\cdot\frac{d(2x^2-1)}{dx}$$

$$=4\cos^3(2x^2-1)\cdot\{-\sin(2x^2-1)\}\cdot(2\cdot2x)$$

Comment: That is, somewhat rearranged, what OP found.

Comment: okay so my answer is the same, but wolframalpha says a dif answer so are they both right or what?

Comment: @user3467226, what's their answer?

Comment: 16 x cos^3(1-2 x^2) sin(1-2 x^2)

Comment: WA has used the relations $ \ \sin (-x) \ = \ -\sin x \ $ and $ \ \cos (-x) \ = \ \cos x \ $ to "swallow" the minus sign.  (The code does many idiosyncratic things to expressions at times.)